# Cannot start Ambari services

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I installed Hortonworks Sandbox via Virtualbox. And when i started ambari every service is stopped like you can see in this screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUq5t.jpg)

I tried to start manually each of the services but nothing happens when i click the start button. And plus, i have many erros in my notifications section.

Also this is what my ambari agent logs looks like [log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc6F3.jpg) [log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA9DS.jpg)

Any idea on how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

@emeric

You must first start HDFS.   You may get warnings that require executing this command:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Once HDFS is started, you can begin to start YARN, and other services.   If you do not have enough resources in your environment you will not be able to start everything.  So only start what you need.